# React Native, Get an array of RGB pixel data from the Filesystem URI of a png file

Tags: image, react-native, expo

I'm writing code where I need to load a PNG file, created by a different function, as an array of RGB values. I have the URI (starting with `file://`) from the expo-filesystem module. The exact format of the array output I get isn't relevant, as I have access to the width and height of the file, and so can reformat it as needed.
How can I get an array of RGB pixel data from the Filesystem URI of a png file?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?